# Top Down Recursive Descent Parsing : Relying on tail call optimization

Tags: c++, parsing, c++11, recursion, optimization

I am building a recursive descent parser and I have two rules which build a list:

```
ValueList  -> TOKEN_IDENTIFER TOKEN_QUOTE ValueListP

ValueListP -> ValueList
           |  %EPSILON%
```

Now I know that you can optimize these two rules into a single rule with a loop easily, but I also know that the compiler can and will perform tail call optimization where it sees it. Here is my current code:

```
void Parser::grammarValueList( std::deque<std::unique_ptr<ValueNode>>& arg1 )                                                                                                                                                                 
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    std::string var1 = m_currentToken.getValue().string;                                                                                                                                                                                  
    if( acceptToken( Token::Type::TOKEN_IDENTIFIER ) )                                                                                                                                                                                    
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            std::string var2 = m_currentToken.getValue().string;                                                                                                                                                                          
            if( acceptToken( Token::Type::TOKEN_QUOTE ) )                                                                                                                                                                                 
            {                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                    arg1.push_back( std::unique_ptr<ValueNode>( new ValueNode( var1, var2 ) ) );                                                                                                                                          
                    if( peekValueListP() )                                                                                                                                                                                                
                    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                            return grammarValueListP( arg1 );                                                                                                                                                                             
                    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

    throw ParseException( "Error: did not expect \"" + m_currentToken.toString() + "\"" );                                                                                                                                                
}

void Parser::grammarValueListP( std::deque<std::unique_ptr<ValueNode>>& arg1 )                                                                                                                                                                
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    if( peekValueList() )                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            return grammarValueList( arg1 );                                                                                                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            return;                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

    throw ParseException( "Error: did not expect \"" + m_currentToken.toString() + "\"" );                                                                                                                                                
}
```

So I have two questions:

1) Does my provided code leverage tail call optimization?

2) Even if a piece of code does leverage tail call optimization, should we as programmers try to make that optimization our self ( removing the recursion and replacing with a loop ) in trivial cases?

Comment: If you want to know if your specific compiler performs tail call optimisation, look at the emitted assembly language code.

Comment: Just because a compiler can doesn't mean that your compiler will. The C++ standard allows the compiler to implement any optimization that is not observable; but the compiler is not required to do that either.

Comment: The simple solution is to use iteration instead of recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `grammarValueList` does not perform a tail call.

The problem is that there are two local variables of type `std::string`, which has a non-trivial destructor. Those destructors must be called just before the method returns, which is after `grammarValueListP` is called. So the call to `grammarValueListP` is not in tail position.

It is, of course, possible that an optimiser with access to the definition of the destructor could figure out that it is possible to prematurely destruct `var1` and `var2` without altering the function's visible behaviour (assuming that it is possible; it depends in part on what happens inside the `ValueNode` constructor). But I don't believe that most C++ implementations try that hard to optimize tail calls.

Personally, I'd use a loop, because even if you manage to eliminate the destructor calls, it is quite possible that the compiler still won't find the TCO. As can be seen in this apparently simple example, tail calls in C++ are often not as trivial as they look on the surface, and it can be surprisingly difficult to convince the optimiser to produce one.